# DB2 i5 no schemas with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, db2, ibm-data-studio

I've got a stored procedure which I need to debug, and seeing how iNavigator is not that good in that regard, I got IBM Data Studio.

In order to be able to debug said procedure, I need to connect using the IBM Driver for JDBC and SQLJ. I took the name of the database from iNavigator, put everything in, hit test connection and I got the OK.

Now, if I open the connection and go in my database, I can see no schemas at all. If I try to perform any kind of operation (even a select) I get this error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSSH200;00;S659e870          , DRIVER=4.18.60
```

Weird thing is, it works perfectly if I use the AS/400 driver, but I just can't have that for debugging. I've scoured the web and I can't find the problem so far.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like [CLI packages are not bound](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0007866.html) to the database. You would need appropriate permissions and at least Data Server Runtime Client to issue the `BIND` command, so you probably need to ask your DBA to do that for you.

Comment: @mustaccio that would be rather weird, considering that both the AS\400 driver as well as System iNavigator work as expected. I'll look into it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to put inot your url connexion

```
jdbc:db2://SERVER400NAME:446/databasename:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;
```

in tab optionnal add this:

```
Libraries=YOURLIB1,YOURLIB2
```

Comment: I already have that url connection. I added the library in the optional tab, didn't change anything. Thank you for the answer.